# Making a checkbox without a boolean in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have the following enum :

```
public enum Type
{
A ,
S
}
```

At the moment I have the following code in my view which uses this enum:

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.Label("Type")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Project.Domain.POCO.Type))))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
</div>
```

However, the original idea was to use a checkbox and not a dropdownlist, this was just a temporarily solution.
Whenever I try using @Html.CheckBoxFor it expects a boolean type, is there any way to work around this and keep using my enumtype instead of creating a boolean (since the enum is used in multiple classes and I'd have to make a lot of changes if I were to change it into a boolean)

Comment: Make a `YourPageViewModel` with a `bool AmIA { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse your enum to a boolean since your enum types are also int values:

A = 0, S = 1..

since you only have two values you always have 0 or 1. This can be parsed into a bool. Note that this is a very dirty solution.

when you use:

```
Boolean.Parse((int)model.Type)
```

you'll get a bool. A = false, S = true

However I wouldn't recommend using this approach

Comment: Allright thanks a lot! 
Why is is considered a dirty solution though? (I'm new to asp.net programming)

Comment: Well, it's not programming safe because when you add more types to this enum you won't be left with only 0 or 1, but also 2 and so on. if this answer helped you, you might consider upvoting it, or even accepting it as an answer (or both)